# I want to fix the shipping price magento based on postcode and weight?

Tags: php, magento

I have to fix the shipping price in magento based on  postcode and weight for example the shipping price for specific postcode is stable upto 20 kg if its exits 20 kg i have to increase the shipping price like 1.30 euros for every kg.how can do that?. I hv already looked the table rates but i think it wnt suit my scenario. Can anyone pls help me.thanks

Comment: Do you have a table of _all_ post codes/prices up to `20kg`? If not how are you getting the initial price for `<20kg`?

Comment: yes i have the table of postcodes/prices upto 20kg. Then how can i fix  the shipping price if it exits 20kg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function like:

```
function calculateShippingFee($parcelWeight, $standardShippingFee){
    $maxWeight     = 20;    //Max weight of parcel before additional cost
    $overWeightFee = 1.30;  //Fee per kg over weight
    $additionalFee = 0; //Initialise additional fee

    if($parcelWeight > $maxWeight){
        $amountOver    = ceil($parcelWeight) - $maxWeight; //Amount over the max weight
        $additionalFee = $amountOver * $overWeightFee; //Additional fee to be charged
    }
    return $standardShippingFee + $additionalFee;
}
```

Which will return the calculated shipping fee. All you have to do is feed it the `$parcelWeight` and `$standardShippingFee` for the postcode, like:

```
$shippingFee = calculateShippingFee(25, 5.30); //Weight == 25kg, Fee == €5.30
```

Example outputs:

```
echo calculateShippingFee(19, 10);   // Outputs: 10
echo calculateShippingFee(20, 10);   // Outputs: 10
echo calculateShippingFee(25, 10);   // Outputs: 16.5
echo calculateShippingFee(24.3, 10); // Outputs: 16.5
```

**Function with changing over weight fee**

```
function calculateShippingFee($parcelWeight, $standardShippingFee, $overWeightFee){
    $maxWeight     = 20;    //Max weight of parcel before additional cost

    $additionalFee = 0; //Initialise additional fee

    if($parcelWeight > $maxWeight){
        $amountOver    = ceil($parcelWeight) - $maxWeight; //Amount over the max weight
        $additionalFee = $amountOver * $overWeightFee; //Additional fee to be charged
    }
    return $standardShippingFee + $additionalFee;
}
```

Comment: thanks steven. Its looked so fine if i hv $overWeightFee is stable but  the actual problem is $overWeightFee is not fixed.It will change according to the postcode and its magento..if i wil try this i must kept my hand into the magento core sections so pls suggest me! can i do this?

Comment: If the over weight fee changes you can change the function to take it as an input (see updated answer). Can you show some example code of how you are currently generating the fees with magento?

Comment: Thanks ur response.I did it steven

Comment: where to put that func?

Comment: @MarcoMarsala It's a stand alone function; in theory you can put it anywhere you like (well, within reason). The best place to put it depends on your set up, but if you only need it on your "checkout" page, you can just add it into that page (normally at the top of the page).

Comment: but it needs to hook into magento internal core... in this way you display the shipping fee, but how Magento know your value, for ex. for invoicing? Wouldn't you need to write a module?

Comment: @MarcoMarsala I'm not sure how @jai implemented it... I have no experience with Magento my self so don't know the answer, though I would assume that you could likely add the function in to the relevant `class` in Magento and modify the code accordingly. Perhaps you could start another question with the code you are currently using to produce _invoices etc._ and I (or someone with knowledge of Magento) could help you implement it? Alternatively, @jai might see this later and be able to tell you how he did it.